# Launch an application on Vista with non-elevated mode from an elevated application

Tags: c#

I have 2 application: app1.exe & app2.exe. app1.exe is elevated and will launch app2.exe.

Because app1.exe is elevated, app2.exe will be launched with elevated mode.
Please help me how app1.exe will call app2.exe with non-elevated mode.

Thanks.

Which way I will use:

1. app1.exe will set non-elevated on app2.exe.
2. app2.exe will drop elevated to non-elevated itseft.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I will use which way:


1. app1.exe will set non-elevated on app2.exe.

2. app2.exe will be drop elevated to non-elevated itseft.


Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching another manged app you can look at appdomains.  Which will give you finer grained control.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of security you **don't** want app1 to launch app2 as elevated and wait for app2 to lower itself.  If a hacker changes app2 then app1 will launch the hacked app2 as elevated.  Though if a hacker can change app1 you're doomed.

Comment: I launch another application with a lower security, I think windows will force this.

Maybe, I will downgrage app1.exe to non-elevated and after that, call app2.exe and app2.exe will also be non-elevated.